# Как в канвасе передать координаты мыши в create_oval

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Как в канвасе передать координаты мыши в create_oval(), чтобы при клике в указанную область создавался овал?

```
from tkinter import *


def b1(event):
    oval = c.create_oval()


def move(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    s = "Движение мышью {}x{}".format(x, y)
    root.title(s)


root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=400, height=300, bg="white")
c.pack()

root.bind('<Button-1>', b1)
root.bind('<Motion>', move)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Точно так же как в функции `move` берете из события координаты курсора мыши, по ним вычисляете координаты ограничивающего прямоугольника овала:

```
r = 10


def b1(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    oval = c.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r)
```